# image not display after upload with new category image upload attribute in magento 2

Tags: magento2, category, image-upload

I have created new custom image uplaoder attribute for category. It's working good. I can upload image in category but when I go to category page, custom image uplaod attribute does not display image.

I follow this link to create custom image upload attribute

> https://belvg.com/blog/how-to-add-image-attribute-to-a-category-in-magento-2.html

Comment: do you mean uploaded image does not display in frontend?

Comment: No uplaoded image not display in category edit page in admin

Comment: Any error in consol or log file?

Comment: No just show cracked image icon